# Assembly.GetTypes via COM takes long time on System.Data.Entity

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, reflection, com

I have a performance problem with a method that locates types that derive from a certain type. It uses reflection to get all assemblies that are currently loaded (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`) and then iterates over all types in each assembly (`Assembly.GetTypes()`) to look for matches. It is implemented in a separate DLL, that may be used in .NET applications, but it is also COM visible, and may be called from VB6 applications.

This method works very well, and it also performs well in many cases. My problem is, in some cases, the GetTypes call on the assembly System.Data.Entity takes a very long time, more than 5 seconds. Here are the key observations:

- It's always System.Data.Entity on which the GetTypes call takes so long, never another assembly. There may be GetTypes calls on 50 other loaded assemblies, but all of them finish instantaneously.
- If the method is called from within a .NET application (e.g. .NET console application), this performance problem never occurs. The GetTypes call always finishes instantaneously.
- If the method is called from within a VB6 application that uses my DLL via COM, the problem occurs often, but not always. I do not know yet, what causes the 5+ seconds time delay to occur sometimes and sometimes not.

I have successfully verified the above observations with minimal test applications, so there is really nothing more involved than what I just mentioned.

I am clueless as to what could cause this issue. Anybody has an idea?

Regards,
Peter.

Comment: This doesn't sound like anymore than a .NET cold start problem.  Yes, it takes a while to get the CLR loaded, find all the assemblies on disk, just-in-time compile all code.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for your response! I see the delay in the debugger while executing the .NET code, so it is not about loading the CLR. Also, since `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` iterates all loaded(!) assemblies (at least [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says so), it does not seem to be about loading any DLLs either. Finally, I dont't know which code should be JIT compiled for yet another call of `Assembly.GetTypes`, just on a different assembly.

Comment: This is undiagnosable from the info you provided.  You'll need to collect more data, do so with a managed profiler.